# XGBoost ranking file format

Tags: xgboost, ranking

The `xgboost` package [has two files](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input_format.html) that must be used for ranking:

1. `train.txt` with the data
2. `train.txt.group` with the group of each observation

I don't understand two things in each file:

1. What should I use as positive/negative classes? In ranking, there is no such thing as a positive/negative class...
2. What should I use as group? Say that I have observations x1 > x2 > x3. How do I express this lexicographical order using groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I asked this question, it seems [the documentation was expanded](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input_format.html):

We need to provide a ".group" file. For example, the file could be

> ```
> 2
> 3
> ```
>
> This means that, the data set contains 5 instances, and the first two
>   instances are in a group and the other three are in another group. The
>   numbers in the group file are actually indicating the number of
>   instances in each group in the instance file in order.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, ranking means **which one is more likely to be a positive sample**. So it's using for sorting test data for information retrieval or recommend.

So, each group should have one positive sample (may be more? I'm not sure).In the file `train.txt`, **the first line** is the instance label (you can see this in the [doc](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/input_format.html#basic-input-format)).

In the group file, each line is one group's size. So the train data should in order by group, not shuffled.

According to your description, maybe `reg:logistic` is what you want——describe x1 > x2 > x3 in [0,1] at the label column, training model and predicting, then groupby data an